# Making a generic jQuery function that identifies a div then does something

Tags: jquery, function

I've made a thumbnail that, when I mouse over it, a dialog box fades in. But, how do I write a generic function so that jQuery identifies that thumbnail (a div class or id, I suppose) and dialog box display its own corresponding text, instead of creating a dialog box one by one for each thumbnail and its own text?

EDIT: Here's the code I have so far:

```
$('.thumb').mouseenter( function(){
$('.descriptionBox').fadeIn('slow');});
```

This is just for one thumbnail.I know I can put a text inside description box, but I'd like to know a way jQuery could take an #id to identify that thumb inside a DIV and display its own

text

inside that DIV, maybe. I don't know if there's something to do with this function and, if so, how could I get from this:

```
$('.thumb').each(function(index));
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn how to write a jQuery plugin, which you can apply to all elements of a class.

Comment: Show some code.. how far have you gotten? What's the existing function?  StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question correctly, it would help to show some code.

If you want your function to recognize the thumbail that has the activity on, you can use $(this).

for example:

```
$(".someClass").mouseOver(function(){
   $(this).find("dialogBox").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: How does this help him write a generic function that works for multiple DIVs?

Comment: I didn't understand his answer properly at first. I added the use of $(this) now.

Comment: Nice. But then what? It will be several thumbnails. I'd like to do something like  " $(identify thumb).show this thumb text".

Comment: I think my edit might solve your problem. Add a certain class to your thumbnails to select them all, and a class to their dialogboxes, then it will fade the dialogbox in for the thumb that has been moused over.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you have a high hill to climb if you're asking how to use the most basic functionality of jQuery.  Basically you attach an event to the non-dynamic parent and add a selector for the dynamic content you want to catch.  Here's a quick example that attaches the event to a thumbnail container, filters for thumbnail elements, and modifies another element accordingly.

```
$("#thumbnailContainer").on("mouseover", ".thumbnailElement", function() {
  $this=$(this);
  $("#dialogContainer")
     .find(".dialogTextElement")
         .text($this.text())
         .end()
     .show()
     .myAddOnThatHidesTheDialogLater()
  ;
});
```

Comment: Yeah... I've completed codecademy's jQuery yesterday. But I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for. I'll try post some code, although it's very basic yet.

Comment: Hey it almost work. thanks. Except that I want jQuery to identify the class.

Comment: Say I have a bunch of DIVs through the body of the page. One has the id #woodstuff and its text "These are made of wood" and other DIV with id #metalstuff" and its text "These are made of metal". I want a generic function wich, when I mouse over my Tree thumbnail, jQuery understands "oh... this is #woodstuff... I must print "These are made of wood". With your code, I should repeat your code replacing #thumbnailContainer with each id one by one  for every thumbnail, right?

Comment: you need a single common selector for all things that exhibit this behavior.  Easiest is to use class within an id as in the example.  All `.dialogTextElement`s within `#thumbnailContainer` will trigger that event handler.   There's probably not much reason to use id's on the lower level elements if they all behave the same.   As to the text content I'd advise putting them in the elements jquery `.data()` (https://api.jquery.com/data/) or use a hidden nested div - something that's the same for all so the generic even handler works.  good luck